# Numbers cannot be used as URL Titles?

Tags: url-title

In 7 years with ExpressionEngine I've never seen this error before when saving a channel entry: Numbers cannot be used as URL Titles

And, there are past existing entries in this site with numbers as URL Titles. Anyone know what might be causing this and if there is a switch to allow them? I can't find anything.

Comment: By the way, ee 2.5.2

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen that error a while back. Just tried it again on 2.4.0. It only happens when using *only* numbers. Throw one character in there and you'll be ok.

Comment: That sounds sensible, because if your URL title was only numbers, EE's `dynamic` parameter wouldn't be able to differentiate URL titles from entry IDs.

Comment: Great point @AdrianMacneil

Answer (score 7):

This is a feature of ExpressionEngine. You won't be able to use numbers alone as URL Titles. If you managed it in the past, it was probably a bug/fluke that it was allowed, or the entry was created in a non-standard way.

In the `content_edit.php` file there's a check for `is_numeric()` that triggers an error.

```
// Is the url_title a pure number?  If so we show an error.
if (is_numeric($data['url_title']))
{
    $error[] = lang('url_title_is_numeric');
}
```

It's probably in the forums in a few spots, but here's one I found straight from [the horse's](http://ellislab.com/team/member/derek-jones) mouth (though it's just stated as fact, not explained): http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/99496/#502754

**Edit** Looks like Lisa beat me too it.

Answer (score 4):

That's odd, you've always had to use an alpha character - not numbers only.  EE would interpret those as IDs rather than URL titles and become very confused. I'm not sure how you'd have number-only URL titles if submitting directly through EE's forms.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use the entry_id of the entry as a segment in your page's url. I often do this and have the entry_id as the last segment. You can then use the {last_segment} tag in your channel entries tag in the entry_id parameter.

Comment: To add to this, if the entry_id is in segment 2 or segment 3 - then EE will treat it as a single entry page and show that entry.